# IIS 7 Redirect to new domain

Tags: iis, url-rewrite-module

Good morning,

I am trying to create a Rewrite rule in IIS to redirect a specific page to a new url however when I apply the rule no redirect happens what am I missing? Code:

```
</rule>
                <rule name="Redirect" enabled="false" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="(.*)" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^(/)?$" />
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain1/server/sdk/" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2/rest/" />
                </rule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding REQUEST_URI to the pattern match

```
<add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain1/server/sdk/" />
```

match url may also work better as

```
<match url="^(.*)$" />
```

also make sure the rule is enabled, your version has `enabled="false"` on it

Here is my full rule

```
<rule name="domain1/server/sdk/" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^(.*)$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain1/server/sdk/" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2/rest/" redirectType="Permanent" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Excellent thank you very much Mike, I did disable my rule after testing it and it did not work which is why it shows enabled=false however I revised the rule per your advice and that worked for me! Incase this is helpful for anyone else in the future my full rule is:

```
<rules>
                <remove name="Portal Redirect" />
                   <rule name="(rule name)" enabled="true" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="Domain2/rest/" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="domain1/server/sdk/rest/" />
                    </conditions>
                </rule>
```